# Can't decode a base 64 string with Convert.FromBase64String()

Tags: c#, base64

I'm using `Convert.FromBase64String()` for decoding a base 64 encoded string. The string actually is a XML file, which has base 64 encoded images in it. E.g.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
```

I get the following exception:

> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Where is the problem? The double base 64 encoding? The string `image/png;base64` in the base 64 encoded data? An online tool has no issues at all.

**Edit:**

Now I tried to remove `image/png;base64` part from the XML file and I still get this error. Then I tried to decode the string `YWJj` with the same error!? If I use this code

```
byte[] dataBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
```

I get the above exception. If I use instead

```
byte[] dataBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String("YWJj");
```

it does work. Encoding of the file is `UTF-8` according to Notepad++. Any ideas?

**Edit 2:**

`String.Equals` says that the two strings `YWJj` are not equal, despite the `Locals` Window shows that they are:

[image: not equal]

BTW the above code doesn't throw the exception, because I use `string test = "YWJj";`. Why does it work with local defined variables, but not with passed strings? I don't think it's a threading problem, because I made the above function, which is only called once.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove `data:image/png;base64,` part?

Comment: Use only encoded part of data as imput to `Convert.FromBase64String()`

Comment: I can't remove it. But the question is if `Convert.FromBase64String()` doesn't work with such strings ...

Comment: Show code how you remove `image/png;base64` and show variable values from debug time.

Comment: @BWA: I removed `image/png;base64` directly from the file, which is then base 64 encoded and saved as a file in the project. Then I read the file in a string and try to decode it.

Comment: @testing mayby some invisible chars are in string? what lenght is datastringbase64? But in my opinion this should work. Strings looks identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've already written I'm reading the base 64 encoded file in and decode it with `Convert.FromBase64String()`. Now I got it working and the reason is completely unknowable. What I've done?

I renamed the file. That's it.

Before I had a filename like `NAME_Something_v1.0.xsl.b64`. Now I use `NAME_Something.b64`. Perhaps it's not the only reason, but I'm accessing the file from an assembly with `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`. I've cleaned the solution before, but I always had the same problem. Now I changed the name back to where it was and it also works ...

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `data:image/png;base64,` part from string to decode.

```
strind data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...";
string[] pd = data.Split(',');

string decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(pd[1]);
```

The part of string `data:image/png;base64,` isn't base64 data. Real encoded data starts after `,`. [Base64 description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). So function [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) accepts only encoded data. Therefore, you need to extract the encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You shouldn't include the `data:image/png;base64,` part, as this isn't actually a part of the base64 string.

**2.** `iVBORw0KGgoAA...` isn't valid either, this is not the full base64 string.

You can solve this by either splitting the string or using regular expressions to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after `data:image/png;base64,` is the actual Base64 string to be decoded.

You can remove the first part of the string like so:

```
ImageAsString = ImageAsString.Substring(input.IndexOf('data:image/png;base64,') + 1);
```